# How to run mysqldump from windows command prompt

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-5.1, command-line

I'm using non-install version of mysql5.1 on Windows.
I have placed "mysql" folder under c:\ and it seems to work fine.

But when I try `C:\>mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -u root -p mydatabase > c:\>mydatabase.sql` from command prompt it doesn't work and gives back only Access Denied.
(It doesn't even ask to enter the password.)

How can I use mysqldump from windows command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it permissions conflict when try create file -

> c:>mydatabase.sql

create new folder c:\backup, change string to

```
C:\>mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -u root -p mydatabase > c:\backup\mydatabase.sql
```

I think it just mistake when type there -

```
c:\>mydatabase.sql
```

it is also not correct, correct:

```
c:\mydatabase.sql
```

correct, but still will return error, right way - create folder

Comment: I just created the folder and it worked! Yes it was a typo ;) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well that appears the correct way as far as you're using right path to binary mysqldump!

Can you confirm if you can login (and it behaves well?): `mysql -uroot -p`

Not sure if there are some security issues!  Run the command prompt as administrator and attempt to run the mysqldump again.